# Calculation of $\int \sqrt{\tan x+2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Calculation of $\displaystyle \int\sqrt{\tan x+2}\;dx$

$\bf{My\; solution::}$ Let $\displaystyle \tan x+2 = t^2 $, Then

$$\displaystyle \sec^2 (x)dx = 2tdt\Rightarrow dx = \frac{2t}{1+\tan^2 x}dt = \frac{2t}{1+(t^2-2)^2}dt$$

So Integral convert into $$\displaystyle \int \frac{2t^2}{(t^2-2)^2+1^2}dt$$

Let $\displaystyle (t^2-2) = u\Rightarrow t^2=u+2\;,$ Then $\displaystyle tdt=\frac{1}{2}du$

Now How can i solve after that

please help me

Thanks

Comment: When you got $\int \frac{1}{1+(t-2)^2}dt$, couldn't you just substitute $t-2$ by $u$, getting $\int \frac{1}{1+u^2}du$, that is equal to $\arctan(u)+c$?

Comment: Thanks JPLF you are saying Right....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using your substitution
\begin{equation*}
t=\sqrt{\tan x+2}
\end{equation*}
we need to integrate 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{I}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{\tan x+2}\,dx=\int \frac{t^{2}}{\left(
t^{2}-2\right) ^{2}+1}\,dt+C,
\end{equation*}
as you show in your edited question. We can reduce it to a table integral if
we factorize the denominator
\begin{equation*}
t^{4}-4t^{2}+5=\left( t^{2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}\right) \left( t^{2}-
\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}\right) 
\end{equation*}
and expand the integrand into partial fractions
\begin{equation*}
\frac{t^{2}}{t^{4}-4t^{2}+5}=\frac{At}{t^{2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}}-
\frac{At}{t^{2}-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}},
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
A=-B=-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}\left( -2+\sqrt{5}\right) .
\end{equation*}
The standard integral we need is the following one
\begin{equation*}
\int \frac{t}{t^{2}+bt+c}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left\vert
t^{2}+bt+c\right\vert -\frac{b}{\sqrt{4c-b^{2}}}\arctan \frac{2t+b}{\sqrt{
4c-b^{2}}}+C,\qquad 4c-b^{2}>0.
\end{equation*}
In the case at hand $4c-b^{2}=4\sqrt{5}-\left( 4+\sqrt{20}\right) =2\sqrt{5}
-4>0$. So

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{t}{t^{2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}}dt &=&\frac{1}{2}\ln
\left\vert t^{2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}\right\vert  \\
&&-\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}\arctan \frac{2t+\sqrt{4+
\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}+C,
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{t}{t^{2}-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}}dt &=&\frac{1}{2}\ln
\left\vert t^{2}-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}\right\vert  \\
&&+\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}\arctan \frac{2t-\sqrt{4+
\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}+C.
\end{eqnarray*}
We thus get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{I}{2} &=&A\left( \frac{1}{2}\ln \left\vert t^{2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+
\sqrt{5}\right\vert -\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}\arctan 
\frac{2t+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}\right)  \\
&&-A\left( \frac{1}{2}\ln \left\vert t^{2}-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}t+\sqrt{5}%
\right\vert +\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}\arctan \frac{2t-
\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}-4}}\right) +C.
\end{eqnarray*}
Substituting back $t=\sqrt{\tan x+2}$ we get the given integral $I=\frac{2I}{
2}=\int \sqrt{\tan x+2}\,dx$.

ADDED. After simplifying I've obtained

\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\frac{\left( 2-\sqrt{5}\right) \sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{4}\ln \left\vert 
\frac{\tan x+2+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}\sqrt{\tan x+2}+\sqrt{5}}{\tan x+2-\sqrt{4+
\sqrt{20}}\sqrt{\tan x+2}+\sqrt{5}}\right\vert  \\
&&+\frac{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{2}\times  \\
&&\qquad \times \left( \arctan \frac{2\sqrt{\tan x+2}-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{
\sqrt{\sqrt{20}-4}}+\arctan \frac{2\sqrt{\tan x+2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{
\sqrt{20}-4}}\right) +C.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$I=\int\sqrt{\tan x+2}\;dx,\>\>\>\>\> J=\int\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt{\tan x+2}}\;dx
$$
and evaluate below with the  substitution  $\tan x+2= \sqrt5 t^2 $
\begin{align}
I+J
= &\ \frac2{\sqrt[4]5} 
\int \frac{1+\frac1{t^2}}{t^2+ \frac1{t^2}-\frac4{\sqrt5}}dt
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5}2-1}}
\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt[4]5(t-\frac1t)}{2\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5}2-1}}\\
I-J
= &\ \frac2{\sqrt[4]5} 
\int \frac{1-\frac1{t^2}}{t^2+ \frac1{t^2}-\frac4{\sqrt5}}dt
=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5}2+1}}
\coth^{-1}\frac{\sqrt[4]5(t+\frac1t)}{2\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5}2+1}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$u=\sqrt{\tan x+2}$$
Then $$x=\tan^{-1}(u^2-2)$$
finding dx is easy, then substitute directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a **comment**, I found amazing to notice that the result of this integration could simply write
$\sqrt{2 + I} . \arctan \sqrt{2 + \tan{x}}/ \sqrt{-2 - I} +   
 \sqrt{2 - I} . \arctan \sqrt{2 + \tan{x}}/ \sqrt{-2 + I}$

Answer (score 0):

By the same substitution of OP: $\displaystyle \tan x+2 = t^2 $. Then the integrand was converted into a rational function with a quartic denominator.
$$
\begin{aligned}
  & \quad \int \sqrt{\tan x+2}\,dx\\& =\int \frac{2t^2}{t^4-4 t^2+5} d t \\
& =\int \frac{2}{t^2+\frac{5}{t^2}-4} d t \\
& = \int \frac{1+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t^2}+\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t^2}\right)}{t^2+\frac{5}{t^2}-4} d t \\
& =\int \frac{d\left(t-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t}\right)}{\left(t-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t}\right)^2+(2 \sqrt{5}-4)}+\int \frac{d\left(t+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t}\right)}{\left(t+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t}\right)^2-(2 \sqrt{5}+4)} \\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}-4}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t}}{\sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}-4}}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}+4}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{t+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{t}}{\sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}+4}}\right) +C\\& =\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}-4}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan x+2-\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{( \sqrt{5}-4)(\tan x+2)}}\right) \\& \quad  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \sqrt{5}+4}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan x+2+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{(2 \sqrt{5}+4)(\tan x+1)}}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$